# Embedded Message on Zastone ZT-X6 / WLN KD-C1

Tags: uhf, equipment-operation, radio-programming

I recently got a couple of very basic Zastone ZT-X6 2W UHF handheld radios. The actual brand seems to be WLN and the model KD-C1 (because the programming software I downloaded from Zastone is named after this WLN model? I know they have a number of different brand names for this one product).

Looking in that KD-C1 programming software, and Chirp as well, there's an option for this device called "Embedded Message" (in Chirp, it's under the Settings-tab on the left for this radio).

I am not familiar with this functionality and I've tried some googling, but thought this would be a better place to ask: what is the meaning of this "Embedded Message"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An embedded message allows you to leave a user defined artifact in the memory of the radio that can be recalled by the programming software. This can be used for things such as to identify the specific radio, to identify the source file from which the radio was programmed, to identify the company or individual that programmed that radio, the time and date it was programmed, etc. Since it is user defined, any use is possible.

I believe this radio has two 32 character lines (line 1 and line 2) for its embedded message that can be programmed and recalled.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info! Yes there's two lines...